# How do I reorganize DIV segments horizontally?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have this structure of divs and I can't change them

```
<div>
  <header>Header</header>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <div>
    <div>FirstDiv</div>
    <div>SecondDiv</div>
  <div>
</div>
```

and I need to replicate the UI from the first screenshot on the second one.
It would be easy if I can have the header and paragraph in one div so I can use flex-box!
But now I do not know what is the simple solution...
[image]

Comment: Using css you can use `display: flex;`, the default flow of flex is row (horizontal), if you want those elements to wrap, use `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: it will not work because I want to have header and paragraph not in row

Answer (score 1):

Use display flex on each of the main div child elements

Answer (score 0):

I added a class for the main wrapper for easier targeting.

The idea is to use both grid and flex.

Grid for the main wrapper, and flex for the inned div with the `first div` and `second div` divs.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper > header,
.wrapper > p {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.wrapper > div {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  display: flex;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <div>
    <div>FirstDiv</div>
    <div>SecondDiv</div>
  <div>
</div>
```

You can of course modify the code to include `grid-gap` or what ever you need, this is example is barebones to achive your layout.

I would also suggest adding classes to all the elemnets so you will have a easier time targeting the elements.